# How to connect a local PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm following along this GitHub link and I want to connect a local PostgreSQL database. How do I find my database name?

https://github.com/timescale/vector-cookbook/blob/main/openai_pgvector_helloworld/openai_pgvector_helloworld.ipynb

I'm at Part 2:
"In this section, we'll store our embeddings and associated metadata.

We'll use PostgreSQL as a vector database, with the pgvector extension.

You can create a cloud PostgreSQL database for free on Timescale or use a local PostgreSQL database for this step. "

```
# Timescale database connection string
# Found under "Service URL" of the credential cheat-sheet or "Connection Info" in the Timescale console
# In terminal, run: export TIMESCALE_CONNECTION_STRING=postgres://<fill in here>

connection_string  = os.environ['TIMESCALE_CONNECTION_STRING']
```

I've have PostgreSQL installed and used this command in Google Colab

```
connection_string  = "postgres://localhost:5432/postgres"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you've installed and started Timescale locally, it will likely have given you all the information you need. You would already have a working PostgreSQL installation, and during its installation you would have learnt how to connect to it. PostgreSQL is not like SQLite where Python can just create a local database based on the library files alone. PostgreSQL requires actual installation, and your Python code can connect to the service.

Comment: I've installed PostgreSQL how can I connect the code to the server?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the right place to get a step-by-step tutorial on how to configure PostgreSQL, then install TimeScale, and then connect your app. There are lots of tutorials out there on getting started with TimeScale that explain this in great detail. If  you find this too complicated, you should follow the cookbook's advice and start with a cloud-based database, following the instructions provided.